# Firefox developer tools: JavaScript files show up as HTML

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpages

Since a few days, the JS debugger in Firefox (68.0.1) doesn't open JS files correctly. Instead, some HTML is displayed. The JS files do not have a file extension at all, yet the Content-Type header correctly contains *application/x-javascript*. Other files with js extension do show up with a JS icon in front of them.

Is this a recent change? What can I do to make those files show up correctly in the debugger?

The application I use is built in XPages, so there might also be some setting there that used to create files with the .js extension, but I'm not sure of that.

**ADDED**

[image: partial screenshot of "javascript" file]

I can tell you that xcsDocument definitely is a JS file, and that Firefox has no problems using it. No JS errors displayed, no HTML errors, nothing significant on the Console tab.

[image]

Comment: the debugger  still works with those files, it just seems to be the icon isn't `js` - is it effecting your debugging?

Comment: Nope, the debugger doesn't work. Instead of showing me the JS code, it displays the HTML that comes with the login page (I think). Chromium and IE (!) seem to have no problem with those files.

Comment: weird, I don't see that if I dummy up what you've described - of course, I may not have gotten it just right (or wrong as the case may be)

Comment: See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1572021

Comment: the image you've shown shows that the file is a document and is served as such - it even has a form in it ... I doubt the debugger is adding all that - are you saying that `xcsDocument` is just javascript on the server?

Comment: No, the file is not a document and does not contain HTML and a form. As I said, xcsDocument really is a JavaScript file, albeit without a .js extension. And Chromium (on Linux) does permit me to debug JavaScript.

Comment: so why does your browser show otherwise - firefox would not add all that (especially a **`<form>`**) - in the console, inspect what the browser is receiving (do a hard refresh on the page, ctrl-f5, and in the console or network tab, inspect the received data)

Comment: That's my question exactly: why do I see HTML when I want to see JavaScript?? By the way, the page behaves correctly, so apparently execution of the JavaScript code is no problem. The HTML shown is the login-page, but the JavaScript is loaded and executed correctly. Ctrl-F5 changes nothing.

Comment: Bug confirmed by Mozilla.

Comment: Oh, so it only occurs if there's no extension at all - that's where I failed to duplicate the issue :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago. Add the .js extension to your client-side javascript design element, and if need be, double-check the custom controls etc where the script is being used to verify the .js extension is there too.

[image: Img of scripts]

[image: img of xpage code]

Comment: Bizarre... that's it! But it's still a work-around IMHO, since it used to work in FF64. So now I have to rename 30 CSJS files? Well, thanks very much Firefox! :-)) I'm not going to rename them all right now, just when I need them. And really thank you Simon! I'll keep the bug report open in Bugzilla.